# Redirect to url with auth header

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to redirect to protected resource. When I press the login button it posts to my unprotected login api and returns a token.

The other routes expect a header "Authorisation: Bearer token" kind of deal, but I don't know how to set the header when I redirect to the protected resource:

```
console.log("success logging in, token retrieved..");
window.localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
window.location.href = '/admin/'; // + '?token='+ data.token;
```

I could pass the token in the query, but that's a bit ugly in my opinion as I have to handle that endpoint differently to how the others are handled...
I also don't want to have to use cookies.

Is there any way to add the header? Maybe I'm going about it wrong...

Comment: I think it is not possible to add headers using window.location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't do it like this. You have to use a query param.